# How to save changes in vim parameters

Tags: vim

I would like to change some vim parameters so I can see the spaces+eol, and set the tabulations as 4 spaces. I found a few commands that allow me to do that but i have to type the commands every time I wanna use them. Is there a way so save them so they stay even when I close vim?

Comment: Lesson 7.2 of `$ vimtutor` is precisely about that very subject.

Answer (score 1):

Put those commands in a [`vimrc`](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#vimrc) file. Vim loads this on startup and runs the commands in it, as if you had typed them in.

See also: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13398/are-there-any-comprehensive-docs-for-vimrc